# How to extend windows partition if it is second partition?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

How to extend windows partition if it is second partition?
on my laptop I have debian and windows dual boot, Debian is at the beginning of the HDD, and the Windows takes last 120GB of my drive.
I can reduce size of debian partition BUT how do I resize windows partition to fit all available space behind (or to the left (if looking at diskpart)) without formatting and reinstalling windows?
The problem is that if you even manage to extend windows partition, you still have Windows at the same exact place on HDD.
What I think is need to be done is:
1) reduce (shrink) debian partition 
2) extend the windows partition
3) boot some utility or LiveUSB and *actually* move windows files to beginning of its partition

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Use **[GParted](http://gparted.org/)** from a live CD to resize and move partitions.

Comment: The question asked "how do I resize windows partition to fit all available space behind (or to the left (if looking at diskpart)) without formatting and reinstalling windows", and that's exactly what GParted does.

Answer (score 1):

1. Clone your Windows partition.
2. Shrink Debian partition and resize Windows partition to according to your needs
3. Format Windows partition and restore from clone.

If you aren't sure about which tool to use I can recommend PartedMagic as it contains all the tools you'll need. (Clonezilla and GParted)